# Using plugin results within channel tags

Tags: parse-order, math

I use this code using exp:math plugin:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="planilla_de_indicadores" limit="10"}

{exp:math formula="([1] / [2]) * 100" parse="inward" params="{ps_talleres2}|{ps_talleres1}" decimals="2" absolute="yes"}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Here are the results:

ps_talleres1: 50 | ps_talleres2: 200 | Result: **25**

The problem is i need to use the result in a conditional like this:

```
{if {exp:math formula="([1] / [2]) * 100" parse="inward" params="{ps_talleres2}|{ps_talleres1}" decimals="2" absolute="yes"} >= "50"}

<span class="badge badge-warning">
{exp:math formula="([1] / [2]) * 100" parse="inward" params="{ps_talleres2}|{ps_talleres1}" decimals="2" absolute="yes"}%
</span>

{/if}
```

As expected; it doesn't work as plugin and tmp parsing order. 
After some google i think maybe "Pre-embed" or "stash" might help... I saw a few answers pointing to "turn plugin into a tag pair" but not sure how.

Comment: Doesn't work why? What's happening? I'm asking because maybe the `random` parameter on one of the plugin tags can help.

Comment: Thanks @robson ...

Actually it's now working, can't say why... I will share

Answer (score 1):

Working

```
    {html_open}
    {html_head_end}
    {html_body}

    {embed="app_includes/header"}
     {contentpanel_open}

{exp:channel:entries channel="planilla_de_indicadores" limit="100"}

{if {exp:math formula="([1] / [2]) * 100" parse="inward" params="{ps_talleres2}|{ps_talleres1}" decimals="2" absolute="yes"} >= "50"}
    <span class="badge badge-warning">
    {exp:math formula="([1] / [2]) * 100" parse="inward" params="{ps_talleres2}|{ps_talleres1}" decimals="2" absolute="yes"}% {title}<br />
    </span>
{/if}

{if {exp:math formula="([1] / [2]) * 100" parse="inward" params="{ps_talleres2}|{ps_talleres1}" decimals="2" absolute="yes"} <= "49"}
    <span class="badge badge-danger">
    {exp:math formula="([1] / [2]) * 100" parse="inward" params="{ps_talleres2}|{ps_talleres1}" decimals="2" absolute="yes"}% {title}<br />
    </span>
{/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}

    {contentpanel_close}
    {embed="app_includes/rightpanel"}

    <!-- define custom page js (if) -->
    {html_close}
```